# Going from sandbox environment to Live PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am experiencing some problems going Live with the webshop i created.

In sandbox:
Im able to use both IPN/PDT and at the pdt.php page the user is sent to after a purchase is showing the products bought since the TX-token has a item_number=SOMETHING which I use to see what products bought and then show material accordingly.

In live:
Im able to use IPN/PDT in the way that mail is sent to the customer as a receipt(IPN) and they are taken to the thankyoupage after the purchase (PDT), but for the PDT the tx-token has item_number=
and nothing more, its empty. This is turn does that stuff do not get preesented since the item_number isnt set, or sent anyway. The IPN is sent but in it the item_name is never showed as it is in the sandbox ipn mail.

Somehow the item_name gets lost when live but not when sandboxing then all is smooth and it "should" work so im stuck.

Please eanyone?

Answer (score 0):

When using [PDT](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/), PayPal should be sending tx=transactionID back to your site, than you have to turn around and do a post back to PayPal to verify the request.  Once you do this, this will be when you get all of the data back such as the item name, number and etc.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input I guess I have to read up on that. But why is it working during sandbox? Is it because when testing the tx-token is automatically VERIFIED without having to do the post back? Which is only needed to in live environment? Where can I read up on the post back thingy?

Comment: Also, this affects IPN too since the mail sent to customer CAN show for example total amount and payer_mail wiht my solution and their name, but not item_name. Is this also fixed by doing that post back?

Comment: Heres my IPN and PDT: http://pastebin.com/tBvkkdyk
http://pastebin.com/uet9nNeX the question now is Where to put this post back? In the IPN or PDT or both?

Comment: Found this: is this sufficient, and after where should I paste it? PHP
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .="POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .="Connection: close\r\n";

Comment: You will want to have a post back in both your IPN and PDT scripts. Once you read the data you will need to append specific information to the post back, and then perform the postback.  This page explains PDT https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

Comment: Sigh. I cant understand this: isnt the CURL-lines the code that does the POSTBACK? I already have this in my ipn... Really cant you try to explain this thoroughly? It would be RLY appreciated. This is some of my code before I checked up on some sample code: http://pastebin.com/YT1SJV1X and this is where I have edited to "match" the code example: http://pastebin.com/hSVRquix

Comment: As you can see  the changes between them is 
1: cmd=_notify-synch TO cmd=_notify-validate, 
2: added the lines curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);, curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1) and lastly 
3: if(!$res){
 //HTTP ERROR
}else {  
//parsedata..
TO: 
if(!$res){
 //HTTP ERROR
}else if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
//parse

Am I on right track? This is the last piece of thing that has to e solved for this project to be done and I cant seem to get it done by myself and I think I could do it with your expert help!

Comment: Sorry that was my PDT. Hers my IPN where Its not quite the same as the PDT and I dont have the CURL-check: http://pastebin.com/MrAFD98p

Comment: The problem with the IPN is that I have done it by myself and other sources than the xcommerce code sample for the IPN and in my solution I insert the purchase into a DB which is neat and I dont know how to edit this file to suit the code from xcommerce - to have the best of both.

Comment: The problem with thee PDT is that its the sam eas the xcommerce code sample for PDT but it still dont work - only in sandbox test environment. Some of the tx-tokens variabls is sent but not all and not the most important ones.

Comment: I ws able to edit the IPN to following: http://pastebin.com/xdq7RUV8 and to get both mails (to customer and to seller as receipt/copy o receipt) sent. This is in sandbox mode so I dont know if its working in "live". Im gonna test this ASAP. But question remains, what should I do with the PDT? Its almost exactly the same as in xcommerce's PDT code sample and its working fully in sandbox, but item_name is lost when going live, so something is not working. Heres PDT: http://pastebin.com/rXmyHkqv